# Touching apple screen with finger nail

Tags: screen

I saw this small dirt mark on my MacBook Air screen, and decided to clean it with a microfibre cleaning cloth. However when I went to clean it I may have pressed to a hard, because a ripple effect appeared.

I think I used my nail to get the small dirt mark off, however the microfibre cleaning cloth was in between the screen and the nail. I know this is a bit over protective but will any harm be caused by the small extra amount of force I put?

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely you caused any damage.  The screens are fairly flexible.

If you aren't seeing any visible damage, or issues with the display in the area you cleaned it, you're okay.